# How to open Apple calendar automaticly when generating ".ics" file

Tags: php, ios, calendar, header, icalendar

all.
So I am sending an email to users with the link to my site. When they press link "add to iCall" they automatically redirected to the page where ".ics" file automatically downloading.

And here is the trouble when I just click that link (from iPhone) it is just an open black page and doing nothing.

But when I am opening the same link through Safari it is automatically open Calendar and everything is work well.

Here are the headers I am sending to generate ics file:

```
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".time().rand(1,100).".ics");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might not like the capital letter "C" in the word "calendar" in the content type.  Try making it lowercase.